# Find hashed data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hash

Is it possible with MongoDB to find data by its hash?

I'm trying to find the MongoDB equivalent of this MySQL query:

`SELECT column FROM table WHERE SHA1(column) = "value"`

Comment: Any reason not to search for the original value?

Comment: In my context, the value would be the id and would be used by the user to confirm something. I don't want the users to confirm the value of someone else since it's not a authenticated part of the application.

Comment: If you want the query to be fast you should store the hashed value in the collection also, and index on it.

Comment: The issue with storing the hash is that i have billions of records so adding a new data to each one would take a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

[It doesn't seems there is any such functionality](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/gL4XCl4PrdA) (a bit old, but couldn't find in *docs.mongodb.com* either), but you can include a library that contains sha1 functionality (e.g. [js-sha1](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1)) in mongo shell with [load](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/) function, then use it within your mongo operation.

Comment: Thanks! Got `true` after loading js-sha1 in mongo shell.
Can you help me figure out how to do the `db.collection.find()` query with this `sha1` function? Also, it seems that I would need to do `load()` at each startup, is there a way to automate this?

Comment: @Leekie I think you can have the load command in your mongodb post-connection creation step in your server startup, for example in spring; while you are generating the `mongoTemplate` [bean](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/), before returning the bean, you can execute the command to load this js library. Sorry I cannot give exact details but the idea is there. I think it is acceptable to load the library during the deployment, but not during each operation as you have said.

Comment: @Leekie was this answer not satisfactory?